# Has anyone painted a basement floor with an epoxy during winter with success?

Tags: basement, flooring, epoxy

I am getting ready to beane doo some black mastic off my floors.  Next I plan on filling any holes (patching), after patching and muriatic acid, epoxy will come next. I have never used an epoxy paint on flooring before and just worry with the temps dropping that it will have an adverse effect on the paint.  I read the instructions and they say 60 degrees or greater will suffice.  I temped the floor and the air and it is at about 70 degrees.  Again just wondering if anyone has had success doing this in winter and if this is something that should wait for a warmer season?

Comment: Hmmm. Black Mastic - have you sent a sample to a lab to be checked for asbestos?

Comment: Yeah, long time ago.  Just finally getting the time to get back to work on this.

Comment: I have used 2 part epoxy floor paint in quite a few basements & garages. If close to the minimum temp it will take longer to fully cure but it has always worked. Make sure it is not the type with VOC's that should be used out side in garages (not inside) I did make this mistake 1 time and had to put the owners up at a hotel for a day on my dime.